# How to change pager jqgrid font size?

Tags: jqgrid, pager

I want to change the font which displays the number of records in the table.
(View 1 - 10 of 13)--> that font specifically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the CSS of whole text `View 1 - 10 of 13` you should override jqGrid default CSS with your own ,

```
.ui-paging-info{
   font-size: 20px;
}
```

#### See the [working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/QEzhr/881/)

But , If you only want to change the CSS of numbers only `13` then you should add a jqGrid property for specifying the view record format using ,

```
recordtext: "View {0} - {1} of <span style=' font-size: 20px;'>{2}</span>",
```

#### See the [working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/QEzhr/882/)

Hope this is what you want.